# iOS Horizontal week calendar

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm currently in a project which requires a sort of timetable. The requirement is a horizontal (scrollable if needed) week view. Something similar like the iOS calendar when holding the device in landscape position.

I managed to find a couple of Cocoacontrols/-pods, but none of them seem to be working properly or display an actual week calendar. The MSCollectionViewCalendarLayout is similar to what i need but it is unable to compile and it took more time to fix than i'd like to.

Any of you got some quick tips to speed up my project?

Comment: go here https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?q=calendar you will find lots off controls.

Comment: Like i said: On Cocoacontrols: It's not that i searched for Rhino cages?

Comment: I needed the same thing and created this:

https://github.com/tonyayoub/HorizontalCalendar/tree/master